# Django Stripe Payment: Invalid card object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

When I try to send a payment to stripe I get an error message: "Invalid card object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string."

The payment is for a set amount of 5 Euros. I am using the credit card number 4242 4242 4242 4242 to test the payment. I can see the 'Post' parameters to stripe are all correct apart from the 'stripe_id'. I have been trying to see what is wrong with 'stripe_id' but I am at a loss.

Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my code?

checkout.html:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}

{% block head_js %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="">
    //<![CDATA[
    Stripe.publishableKey = '{{ publishable }}';
   // ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/stripe.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'checkout' %}" method="post" id="payment-form" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <legend>Payment Details</legend>

    <div id="credit-card-errors" style="display: none;">
        <div class="alert-message block-message error" id="stripe-error-message"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        {{ payment_form|as_bootstrap }}
    </div>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <input class=" btn btn-primary" id="submit_payment_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit Payment of 5 Euros">
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```py
from django import forms

class MakePaymentForm(forms.Form):
    print("MakePaymentForm...")
    MONTH_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(1, 12)]
    YEAR_CHOICES = [(i, i) for i in range(2019, 2040)]
    
    credit_card_number = forms.CharField(label='Credit Card Number', required=False)
    cvv = forms.CharField(label ='Security Code (CVV)', required=False)
    expiry_month = forms.ChoiceField(label="Month",choices=MONTH_CHOICES, required=False)
    expiry_year = forms.ChoiceField(label='year',choices=YEAR_CHOICES, required=False)
    stripe_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,  required=False)
```

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import MakePaymentForm
from tickets.forms import TicketsForm
from tickets.models import Ticket
from django.conf import settings
from accounts.views import login, index 
from django.utils import timezone
import stripe
# Create your views here.

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET

@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm(request.POST)
        print("checkout...")

        if  payment_form.is_valid():
            print("Payment form is valid...")
            try:
                print("Just about to charge the customer...")
                customer = stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount=500,
                    currency="EUR",
                    description="Thank you for your contribution, it will really help our site" and request.user.email,
                    card=payment_form.cleaned_data['stripe_id']
                )
            except stripe.error.CardError:
                messages.error(request, "Your card was declined!")
            
            if customer.paid:
                print("Customer has paid...")
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully paid")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Unable to take payment")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            print("There are errors...")
            print(payment_form.errors)
            messages.error(request, "We were unable to take a payment with that card!")
    else:
        print("Method isn't post...")
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm()

    return render(request, "checkout.html", {"payment_form": payment_form, "publishable": settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE})
```

Here is the output in the terminal:

```
Method isn't post...
[18/Dec/2020 23:24:26] "GET /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5957
checkout...
Payment form is valid...
Just about to charge the customer...
Internal Server Error: /checkout/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/checkout/views.py", line 29, in checkout
    card=payment_form.cleaned_data['stripe_id']
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 22, in create
    response, api_key = requestor.request("post", url, params, headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 122, in request
    resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 373, in interpret_response
    self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/issuetracker/foo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 152, in handle_error_response
    raise err
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_KWiO7eNBrSt4ph: Invalid card object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string. See API docs at https://stripe.com/docs'
[18/Dec/2020 23:24:40] "POST /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 104672
```

and here is stripe.js:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#payment-form").submit(function() {
        console.log("#payment-form");
        var form = this;
        var card = {
            number: $("#id_credit_card_number").val(),
            expMonth: $("#id_expiry_month").val(),
            expYear: $("#id_expiry_year").val(),
            cvc: $("#id_cvv").val()
        };
    
    Stripe.createToken(card, function(status, response) {
        console.log("#createToken");
        if (status === 200) {
            $("#credit-card-errors").hide();
            $("#id_stripe_id").val(response.id);

            // Prevent the credit card details from being submitted
            // to our server
            $("#id_credit_card_number").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_cvv").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_month").removeAttr('name');
            $("#id_expiry_year").removeAttr('name');

            form.submit();
        } else {
            $("#stripe-error-message").text(response.error.message);
            $("#credit-card-errors").show();
            $("#validate_card_btn").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a screen print of my page when the payment fails:

[image: Screen Print after attempted payment 1]
[image: Screen Print after attempted payment 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the  answer and the credit card payments are working fine now. I hadn't included the jQuery CDN in the header so stripe.js wasn't being called correctly!

Thanks Justin Michael, you triggered something in my brain that set me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the request in your Stripe Dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_KWiO7eNBrSt4ph

You can see there that the value of `card` is an empty string, which is why you're getting the error.

It looks like this code on your frontend is preventing the card information from being sent to your server:

```
// Prevent the credit card details from being submitted
// to our server
$("#id_credit_card_number").removeAttr('name');
$("#id_cvv").removeAttr('name');
$("#id_expiry_month").removeAttr('name');
$("#id_expiry_year").removeAttr('name');
```

As a result your server has nothing to send in the `card` property.

Stripe.js v2 is quite out of date; I recommend you [upgrade to Stripe.js v3 and Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/migrating) if possible.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have removed those lines but I still get the same error. I am quite a novice at django and stripe so I am not sure if that is what I was supposed to do. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: My primary recommendation is to [migrate from Stripe.js v2 to Stripe.js v3](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/migrating), which will require you to rewrite a lot of this code, but you'll end up with a much better integration (and likely less PCI compliance burdens) as a result.

Comment: Actually, I think stripe.js isn't being called properly as the output to the console.log isn't being displayed. Could this be the problem?